# twitter integration in android application

Tags: android, twitter

Hi all how to integrate twitter in android application without authentication ?
i want to twit my status through my application . using oauth i have done twitter in my application but using oauth twit updated and it is only for one user .

Comment: but using oauth twit updated and it is only for one user???

Comment: from my twitter id i created customerkey ,secratekey ...i used this key in my application and my status will be updated in my twitter account . there is no any login information in coding .so how to twitt for different use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> from my twitter id i created
>   customerkey ,secratekey ...i used this
>   key in my application and my status
>   will be updated in my twitter account
>   . there is no any login information in
>   coding .so how to twitt for different
>   use ?

You are correct, that when you setup an android app to authenticate using OAuth, you do not programatically include any user details - however, when you first used your app, the app code will have directed you to Twitter to authorise the app to make updates for you - that is when you will have entered your normal Twitter login details, and this is why the app is posting tweets in your user id. For example, if you loaded the app on to another device for someone else to use, they would have to authorise the app to make updates/post tweets and if they put in their user details it would post as them.

There is no possible way to allow updates to multiple accounts without OAuth - as then you would be able to post tweets for other people - however, the correct OAuth implementation allows the phone user to authorise your app once and then continue to update for their user.

It sounds like you have already sorted the user authorisation on twitter and consumer key/secret stuff sorted but there is an overview of OAuth with Android and Twitter (including source code) [here](http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-twitter-oauth-authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

Posting to Twitter *without* authentication is not possible. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: he/she is new to this site and their questions didn't get enough view and answers so we should not mention about Accept Ratio.